# Computing a weighted Average per observation (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have the following two variables, and I am trying to compute the unemployment rate with each observation's individual weight. The first variable below shows the weight given to each individual respondent, while the second variable shows whether the person is unemployed where 1 indicates the individual is unemployed, and 0 if they are working. Finally, LF_status indicates in string format the labor force status.

```
dataex (ind_wt   unemp_status)   LF_status
.42645285         0                emp
 .11840937        1                unemp
 .11849173        0                emp
   1.49918        1                unemp
```

I have taken Cybernike's post, and the values for the newly created weighted unemployment variable looks as follows for all observations, does that make sense?

```
egen unemployment_weighted= wtmean(unemp_status), weight(ind_wt)
dataex unemployment_weighted
.3786077
.3786077
.3786077
.3786077
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `_GWTMEAN` package from SSC to do this. There are probably other ways too.

```
ssc install _gwtmean

egen wanted = wtmean(unemp_status), weight(ind_wt)

. list

     +--------------------------------+
     |   ind_wt   unemp_~s     wanted |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. | .4264528          0   .5549336 |
  2. | .1184094          .   .5549336 |
  3. | .1184917          0   .5549336 |
  4. |  1.49918          0   .5549336 |
  5. | .7357956          .   .5549336 |
     |--------------------------------|
  6. | .8300208          0   .5549336 |
  7. | 4.741648          0   .5549336 |
  8. | 9.495796          1   .5549336 |
     +--------------------------------+
```

Comment: If you're calculating one mean with weights, `summarize` will do it.

Comment: The code works well, but how can I use the newly created variable to compute weighted unemployment by gender or education? Would this work: ```bysort gender: summarize unemployment_weighted```?

Comment: The code `wtmean()` cited here doesn't come with a help file, but just look at the code to see that a `by()` option is supported. In any case any weighted mean is of the form SUM (weight * value) / SUM (weight) and so can be calculated in a few lines with applications of `egen`'s `total()` function, or indeed otherwise. In general if you want results in variables, `summarize` is at best the first step; commands that do it in one are usually available, e.g. `egen`.